# TinyMCE increasing font automatically

Tags: tinymce

Something very odd is happening in my tineMCE.
If I type in bold something between hash tags, for instance, `#Text#` and hit enter, it deletes the first hash tag and increase the font size. Does anybody had this issue?

```
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#mytextarea',
        theme: 'modern',
        skin: 'lightgray',
        menubar: false,
        branding: false,
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
            "table contextmenu directionality emoticons template textcolor paste fullpage textcolor colorpicker textpattern",
            "pagebreak"
        ],

        setup: function (editor) {

        },

        toolbar1: "newdocument fullpage | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | styleselect formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect",
        toolbar2: "cut copy paste | searchreplace | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote | undo redo | link unlink anchor | insertdatetime preview | forecolor backcolor",
        toolbar3: "table | hr removeformat | subscript superscript | charmap | print fullscreen | ltr rtl | spellchecker | visualchars visualblocks | pagebreak",
        init_instance_callback: "renderEditor",
        height: "300"
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading the `textpattern` plugin which is interpreting the first `#` as markdown.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/textpattern

If you don't want the editor to interpret the text as markdown don't load that plugin.

In your particular example the leading `#` is becoming an H1 tag hence the text gets larger as an H1 is likely expected to be larger than a P based on the CSS passed to the editor.

Comment: Perfect. I just removed the textpattern plugin and it worked. Thanks